# Regex Replace does not replace the following

Tags: c#, xml, regex

I need to replace:

```
string full = &lt;para number="3."&gt;Rule 33.12 of the Federal Court Rules 2011(&ldquo;FCR&rdquo;) regulates the practice and procedure to be followed with respect to appeals from the Tribunal. It relevantly provides:&lt;/para&gt;&lt;item&gt;(2) The notice of appeal must state: &lt;/item&gt;&lt;item&gt;(a) the part of the decision the applicant appeals from or contends should be varied; and &lt;/item&gt;&lt;item&gt;(b) the precise question or questions of law to be raised on the appeal; and &lt;/item&gt;&lt;item&gt;(c) any findings of fact that the Court is asked to make; and &lt;/item&gt;&lt;item&gt;(d) the relief sought instead of the decision appealed from, or the variation of the decision that is sought; and &lt;/item&gt;&lt;item&gt;(e) briefly but specifically, the grounds relied on in support of the relief or variation sought. &lt;/item&gt;&lt;item&gt;Note: The Court can only make findings of fact in limited circumstances—see section 44(7) of the AAT Act. &lt;/item&gt;&lt;para number="4."&gt;
```

with this:

```
string full = &lt;para number="3."&gt;Rule 33.12 of the Federal Court Rules 2011 (&ldquo;FCR&rdquo;) regulates the practice and procedure to be followed with respect to appeals from the Tribunal. It relevantly provides:&lt;quote&gt;&lt;para&gt;(2) The notice of appeal must state: &lt;list&gt;&lt;item&gt;(a) the part of the decision the applicant appeals from or contends should be varied; and &lt;/item&gt;&lt;item&gt;(b) the precise question or questions of law to be raised on the appeal; and &lt;/item&gt;&lt;item&gt;(c) any findings of fact that the Court is asked to make; and &lt;/item&gt;&lt;item&gt;(d) the relief sought instead of the decision appealed from, or the variation of the decision that is sought; and &lt;/item&gt;&lt;item&gt;(e) briefly but specifically, the grounds relied on in support of the relief or variation sought. &lt;/item&gt;&lt;item&gt;Note: The Court can only make findings of fact in limited circumstances—see section 44(7) of the AAT Act. &lt;/item&gt;&lt;/list&gt;&lt;/quote&gt;&lt;/para&gt;&lt;para number="4."&gt;
```

I use this code:

```
line = Regex.Replace(line, full, fullNew);
```

the line variable contains the whole xml file.

Please help. Need this badly. Please

Comment: It seems you need string.replace instead of regex.replace, better an xml parser.

Comment: can you show me how to use string replace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's too easy. It needs 2 string values, old and new one as mentioned below:

```
 string.Replace(oldValue, newValue) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
String line = "Whole xml";

string full = "&lt;para number="3."&gt;Rule 33.12 of the Federal Court Rules 2011(&ldquo;FCR&rdquo;) regulates the practice and procedure to be followed with respect to appeals from the Tribunal. It relevantly provides:&lt;/para&gt;&lt;item&gt;(2) The notice of appeal must state: &lt;/item&gt;&lt;item&gt;(a) the part of the decision the applicant appeals from or contends should be varied; and &lt;/item&gt;&lt;item&gt;(b) the precise question or questions of law to be raised on the appeal; and &lt;/item&gt;&lt;item&gt;(c) any findings of fact that the Court is asked to make; and &lt;/item&gt;&lt;item&gt;(d) the relief sought instead of the decision appealed from, or the variation of the decision that is sought; and &lt;/item&gt;&lt;item&gt;(e) briefly but specifically, the grounds relied on in support of the relief or variation sought. &lt;/item&gt;&lt;item&gt;Note: The Court can only make findings of fact in limited circumstances—see section 44(7) of the AAT Act. &lt;/item&gt;&lt;para number="4."&gt;"

string fullnew = "&lt;para number="3."&gt;Rule 33.12 of the Federal Court Rules 2011 (&ldquo;FCR&rdquo;) regulates the practice and procedure to be followed with respect to appeals from the Tribunal. It relevantly provides:&lt;quote&gt;&lt;para&gt;(2) The notice of appeal must state: &lt;list&gt;&lt;item&gt;(a) the part of the decision the applicant appeals from or contends should be varied; and &lt;/item&gt;&lt;item&gt;(b) the precise question or questions of law to be raised on the appeal; and &lt;/item&gt;&lt;item&gt;(c) any findings of fact that the Court is asked to make; and &lt;/item&gt;&lt;item&gt;(d) the relief sought instead of the decision appealed from, or the variation of the decision that is sought; and &lt;/item&gt;&lt;item&gt;(e) briefly but specifically, the grounds relied on in support of the relief or variation sought. &lt;/item&gt;&lt;item&gt;Note: The Court can only make findings of fact in limited circumstances—see section 44(7) of the AAT Act. &lt;/item&gt;&lt;/list&gt;&lt;/quote&gt;&lt;/para&gt;&lt;para number="4."&gt;"

line.Replace(full,fullnew)
```

## [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)